# users management

Tags: user-management

I need to build an application that manages users and I thought that it will be nice to follow an existing management model, like the one used by Windows or linux, that has users, groups, permissions etc.

I couldn't find any place on the Internet to get explanations about how to implement this.

My application is a web application, probably asp.Net (less important the technology) that manages users. I have few levels, for now system administrators, power users, group managers and simple users.

Each level offers privileges, like power users may see all the users, may promote a user to be up to group manager, may degrade a user (with less powers than his) etc.

There is any place where I can read about how to implement such system?

Answer (score 0):

Probably using the [ASP.NET membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) will work for you. You can use the [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) which stores the security information in a Sql Server database. If you need more advanced features (and probably more secure), you can use Active Directory or [ADAM](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4201) with the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx). The ASP.NET membership provider model is customizable and you can implement your own provider, but the existing ones are quite powerful.

Comment: Before to chose how to implement this I'd like to see how others built this kind of structure. My application manages users and user's data from different places (external web services, 2 sql servers, Active directory etc). And I need to find a way to handle the permissions for the users. For example, a simple user cannot change data in Active Directory, except part of his data. Another example, a group manager can see only his group details and statistics (statistics I get from a web service) etc. I'd like to read some theory about this, and I couldn't find.

Comment: It seems that you need to handle custom permissions and the membership provider will only help you with the user management and group membership. For permissions I think you need to implement the [`IPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.ipermission.aspx) interface. The required method is `Demand`. It is true that there are not many examples on MSDN, but it's easy to figure out: in your implementation of `Demand` get the current principal and assess the required permission to perform some action. If the principal does not have it, throw a `SecurityException`.